# Nested object in `DS.attr()` isn't affected by `DS.rollbackAttributes()`

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model `User` as follow:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

const { attr, Model } = DS;

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr("string"),
  properties: attr(),
});
```

`User.properties` is intended to hold a JSON object.

I am updating the model through a form (using [ember-one-way-controls](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-one-way-controls)) as follow:

```
{{one-way-textarea
  model.name
  update=(action (mut model.name))}}

{{one-way-textarea
  model.properties.description
  update=(action (mut model.properties.description))}}
```

I have a button allowing the user to discard the changes by calling a `discardChanges` action:

```
actions: {
  discardChanges(model) {
    model.rollbackAttributes();
  },
},
```

The `name` attribute changes are correctly discard / reset but the `properties` attribute is not.

How can I handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Origin of the problem**

Ember Data isn't aware of the changes because it uses `===` operator to compare the dirtied attribute against the original one. If a change has been spotted, Ember Data stores the dirtied attribute key in the `_attributes` array. [We notice this here.](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/91d8977f815371a744661f52a2cbcfae8f9cd745/addon/attr.js#L145-L148) Then, when you call `DS.rollbackAttributes()`, the model looks at the `_attributes` to acknowledge the attributes to restore. [Here it is.](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/91d8977f815371a744661f52a2cbcfae8f9cd745/addon/-private/system/model/internal-model.js#L560)

*But the hash aren't the same !*

JS is all about value passed by reference. Here is an example from Node interpreter:

```
> var foo = { description: 'hello' }
undefined
> var bar = foo;
undefined
> bar.description = 'bonjour';
'bonjour'
> bar === foo
true
```

You are modifying the original object.

**Solution**

A possible solution is to deep-copy your `properties` object and manually reset it when calling `discardChanges`.

You can implement it as a service :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { copy, Service } = Ember;

export default Service.extend({
  savedProperties: null,

  finalize() {
    this.set('savedProperties', null);
  },

  start(model) {
    const properties = copy(model.get('properties'));
    this.set("savedProperties", properties);
  },

  undo(model) {
    const savedProperties = this.get('savedProperties');
    for (const property in savedProperties) {
      if (savedProperties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        const keyPath = `properties.${property}`;
        model.set(keyPath, savedProperties[property]);
      }
    }
    this.set('savedProperties', null);
  },
});
```

- You call `start` when you enter in edition mode.
- You call `undo` when you want to discard the changes.
- You call `finalize` when you *successfully* saved your record.

Comment: You could also correctly call this a bug, which has existed since day one. It has been the topic of many a question here on SO. Bottom line is that you someone need to manage dirty sub-objects yourself; `notifyPropertyChange` is one option, if that isn't deprecated by now.